# How to avoid the box movement on hover?

Tags: html, css, sass, jsx

I build a navigation block that based on `li` tag and looks as following [screencasts](http://www.screencast.com/t/UHKBjhq2). As you can see, the whole box is moving, *the question how to avoid the box movement?*

The html is a component of ReactJs:

```
<li className="nav-item">
  <a className="nav-link" href={href}>
    {children}
    <span className="pl-3 nav-link-text font-weight-bold">{ReasonReact.string(text)}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

And the styles based on scss:

```
  >.nav-item {
    >.nav-link {
      color: #515253;
      &:hover {
        color: #85899B;
        border-left: 5px solid #37BDE7;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: add `box-sizing:border-box` or define the border initially with transparent color

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent `border-left` to the non-hovered state:

```
 >.nav-item {
    >.nav-link {
      color: #515253;
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      &:hover {
        color: #85899B;
        border-left-color: #37BDE7;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a border you could use an inset `box-shadow`

```
a:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 5px 0 0 #37BDE7;
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjRKYO)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also add left border on hover before like,

>.nav-item {
    >.nav-link {
      color: #515253;
      position:relative;
      &:hover {
        color: #85899B;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
      &:hover:before{
       content: '';
       height: 100%;
       width: 5px;
       background: #37BDE7;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
      }
    }
  }
```